# How to use grunt-browoserify to access my module from the script tag

Tags: gruntjs, global, browserify

I have a simple browserify setup in my `Gruntfile.js`

```
browserify: {
    dist: {
        src: 'public/js/main.js',
        dest: 'public/js/bundle.js'
    }
}
```

But how can I access party of my code from the browser? It seems like the module is completely encapulated. But I need to access some methods from `<script>` tags in my output.

From the console this works `browserify -s myExport public/js/main.js -o public/js/bundle.js`
But I can't get `grunt-browserify` to execute that.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with this (working):

```
browserify: {
    options: {
        transform:  [ require('grunt-react').browserify ],
        browserifyOptions: {
            debug: true,
            standalone: 'myExport'
        }
    },
    dev: {
        src: 'public/js/main.js',
        dest: 'public/js/bundle.js'
    },
    dist: {
        src: 'public/js/main.js',
        dest: 'public/js/bundle.js'
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, the `standalone` option is the important one there. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Wasn't the option to find, was to find how to put it into the option. The documentation lacks some details there.